# Doubt regarding inductors and transformers

Tags: transformer, inductor

If inductors block AC then how come transformers work only on AC? Please clear my concept.

Comment: Inductor block AC ?? I thought inductor offer more reactance to ac compared to dc (where reactance is zero ) at steady State

Answer (score 2):

Well, a big feature of transformers is the huge primary inductance which opposes AC current

Without it, the transformer would draw a lot of current even with no load. So it must have enough primary inductance to make no-load current very low.

Inductance is why 50Hz transformers are huge, but switching supplies' transformers which work at much higher frequency can be tiny.

But... [how does it transform then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer)?

Without load it works like an inductance. Primary current creates varying magnetic flux, which creates counter-emf in the primary [(\$ e = - N_1 d\Phi/dt \$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) which opposes mains voltage, and opposes current flow. This is how an inductance works. N is number of turns, \$ \Phi \$ is magnetic flux which is proportional to N times current.

The secondary is wound on the same core, so it gets the same flux and also produces a voltage \$ e = - N_2 d\Phi/dt \$. So you get a voltage transformer ratio \$ N_1/N_2 \$ according to number of turns.

And if current is drawn from the secondary, magnetic flux in the core is reduced in absolute value, which reduces counter-emf on the primary side, which draws in more current from mains into the primary, which brings flux back to where it was. When the transformer has a load on the secondary, the primary no longer behaves like an inductance at all. It's very simple, yet extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

> *If inductors block AC then how come transformers work only on AC?*

Inductors don't block AC - they have a reactive impedance (somewhat equivalent to resistance in a resistor) that linearly rises with frequency and is governed by this formula: -

$$\text{Inductive Reactive Impedance} = 2\cdot\pi\cdot f\cdot L$$

After all a resistor having 1 kohm resistance or 100 ohms or 10 ohms doesn't prevent it being used at DC or AC.

An ideal inductor will work at DC and many transformers can work at low frequencies but the practical limitation is the rising magnetization current and the onset of core saturation: -

[image]

The above shows a transformer operating at DC and the rise of magnetization current (that eventually leads to excessive current draw and core saturation). Taken from [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/?LMCL=mWla1h#transformers). That rise is governed by the relationship between applied voltage and rate of change of current: -

$$V = L\cdot \dfrac{di}{dt} \hspace{1cm} \text{ or }\hspace{1cm} \dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}$$

To avoid the gradual increase in current becoming excessive, we say that transformers must be operated with an AC drive signal but, we only say that to avoid the problems of having to provide that current and the potential onset of core saturation.

In a perfect ideal transformer we don't need to say that.

So, with an AC applied signal, as soon as the applied voltage reverses, the rate of change of current becomes negative and the core starts demagnetizing eventually to begin magnetizing in the opposite polarity. Therefore we say transformers must be operated at AC so that the resulting peak core magnetic flux doesn't get excessive.